# How to handle Task on App Initialization in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms app. I need to check every time that code is valid or not at app initialization time. I am using below code. It works fine for first time. But when I am pressing back button and reopen app, got app is crashed. Getting NullReference error. How can I handle this on App start up?
My code is :

```
public  App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingClass.SiteCode) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(SettingClass.SiteId))
                MainPage = new LoadScreenPage();
            else
            {
                Task.Run(async () => { var sitecode = await SettingClass.DataServiceObj.GetSiteCodeInformation(SettingClass.SiteCode);                    

                if (sitecode != null)
                {
                    if (sitecode.Id != null)
                    {
                        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
                        mainPage.SelectedItem = mainPage.Children[1];
                        MainPage = mainPage;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MainPage = new LoadScreenPage();
                    }
                }
                }).Wait();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Is this right. If right then why I am getting error?
If not proper way to handle this then what is the other option?

Comment: 1st) You should never block the main/UI thread, especially in a constructor, and even more so in the Application class. 2nd) What actually is null? `sitecode`? thus you are never setting a `MainPage`... in your catch, write out the full Exception so you can determine actually what is null when the debugger is not attached.

Comment: No site code is not null.

Comment: Setup through the code with the debugger.... it might not be in you App class, but somewhere else...

Comment: I had do that. Getting error at Application MainPage initialization. Don't know why.

Comment: Any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - you don't want to handle tasks on app initialization. "Tasks" meant to be a potentially long running procedures. Commonly used to download or process data. You don't want to delay your app start because of that, right? Beside that, currently, there is no way to mark a constructor with `async` keyword.

What you could do for example, is to move your `Task` to one of the application's lifecycle events like `OnStart()` which can be marked as `async`. However why not to let the application load successfully, show some ui to user and than do whatever you need to do in a dummy page?

Comment: I have tried on OnStart() method but it still provides me nullrerence error. While nothing is null in sitecode.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and debug. Moving a non working piece of code from one place to another for sure will not solve the problem.

Comment: I have do that. But Application MainPage is not initializing so Getting NullReference Error.

Comment: Quick and dirty fix -> create an intermediate loader page and move the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `else` part to the if `sitecode` is null

```
if (sitecode != null)
{
    if (sitecode.Id != null)
    {
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        mainPage.SelectedItem = mainPage.Children[1];
        MainPage = mainPage;
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage = new LoadScreenPage();
    }
}
else
{
    MainPage = new LoadScreenPage();
}
```